# Promised Function resolving automatically before full execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I want to block any other execution until **evaluateTestCases** function finishes but before the function finishes, It goes in other function that is **then** of same function.

Here is the function:

```
function evaluateTestCases(source, lang)
        {
            return new Promise(function(resolve)
            {
                for(let i=0;i<hiddenData.testCases.length;i++)
                {
                    getOutput(source, lang, hiddenData.testCases[i].input).then(function(response){
                        console.log(hiddenData.testCases[i].output.toString().trim()===response.output.toString().trim());
                        if(hiddenData.testCases[i].output.toString().trim()===response.output.toString().trim())
                        {
                            points+=1;
                        }
                    });
                }
                resolve(points);e
            });
        }
```

Here is the function call:

```
$("#submit").on("click",function()
            {
                evaluateTestCases(editor.getValue(), $('#language').val()).then(function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                });
            });
```

Now, what happens is: before **evaluateTestCases** function finishes off, `console.log(result);` gets executed and since result is not yet defined, it acts as an error for me.

Comment: The `for` loop is not going to wait for the `getOutput` promise to resolve. Can you use `async/await`? That's the easiest solution.

Comment: You are not waiting for the promise returned by `getOutput(...).then`  to be settled.

Comment: @MarkMeyer can anyone explain async/await for this problem... I'm fully confused

Comment: The function `getOutput` is asynchronous. You call it, it fires off a request and then moves on. The for loop won't wait for the request to return something. Some time in the future the request returns with a result and `then()` is called. But that is *long* after the for loop has finished and you have called `resolve()`. @trincot's answer below shows how to make the for loop wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating promises in the loop, but you are not waiting for them to be settled.

Either use `Promise.all` (if multiple `getOutput` calls may be triggered before they signal completion), or use `await getOutput(...)`. The latter solution will wait for each returned promise to be settled before continuing into the next iteration of the loop. You need to make the outer function `async`:

```
async function evaluateTestCases(source, lang) {
    let points = 0; // Not sure where you were initialising this...
    for (let i = 0; i < hiddenData.testCases.length; i++) {
        const response = await getOutput(source, lang, hiddenData.testCases[i].input);
        console.log(hiddenData.testCases[i].output.toString().trim() === response.output.toString().trim());
        if (hiddenData.testCases[i].output.toString().trim() === response.output.toString().trim()) {
            points+=1;
        }
    });
    return points;
}
```

The main function call can remain like you had it.

Comment: synchronization inside loop is totally OK... it executes serially but two functions are not in sync

Comment: Yes, I still have **then** and I need the loop to finish first and then **then** should be fired... but currently before loop finishes, **then** is fired...

Comment: ahhh... i found the errorneous code... I was missing an **async** keyword, really sorry and thanks